# Intel MKL OOP Wrapper Design and Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, blas, intel-mkl

I started writing an oop wrapper for Intels MKL library and came across some design issues. I hope you can help me find the "best" way to handle these issues. The issues are mainly concerning operator overloading and are not critical two the wrapper but effect readability and/or performance.

---

The first issue is overloading operators considering how the blas functions are defined. As an example, matrix multiplication is defined as

[image: eq]

([image: eq] being matrices, [image: eq] scalars). 
Now i can overload [image: eq] , [image: eq] and [image: eq] alone, but for the implementation of BLAS I would need 4 function calls using overloaded operators instead of one. Or i could use a normal function call (which will be implemented anyway), but lose the "natural" way of writing the equation using overloaded operators, making it less readable (but still more readible than with those horrible BLAS names).

---

The second issue is read and write access to the matrices. As example we can consider the following upper triangular matrix:

[image: mat]

This matrix would be stored efficiently in a 1D array like this (order may vary depending on row/column major order):

[image: mat]

Since a matrix has two indices, the easiest way to overload reading would be using

```
<TYPE> & operator() (size_t row, size_t column);
```

instead of some work around with subscript operators. The problem is handling the zeros. They may not be stored in the array, but mathematically they exist. If I want to read these values in another function (not MKL) I may need to be able to return the zero to handle this (aside from storing the matrix type, which is done for BLAS anyway).

Since () returns a reference, I can't return 0. I could make a dummy variable, but if I were to write to that value, I wouldn't have a upper triangular matrix anymore. So I would have to either change the matrix type, forbid writing to these elements, or ignore it (bad idea).

To change the matrix type I would need to detect writing, that would require explicitly using some kind of proxy object.

To prevent writing, I would probably have to do the same since I can't return a const value because the overload doesn't fit that definition. Alternatively I could forbid writing this way in general, but then I couldn't change the existing matrix itself, which I don't want.

---

I hope you can give me some pointers on how to handle these issues and what design principles I may be forgetting/should take into account. As I said, they are not critical (I can write appropriate functions for everything instead of operators).

T

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for medical image reconstruction https://github.com/kvahed/codeare. The matrix object there has a lot of overloaded operators and convenience function to allow one to write efficiently matlab-like code in c++.

What you want to do for passing the data between MKL and other libraries / algorithms is in my view impossible. How do you want to distinguish 0 from 1e-18. What when you want to go to some numeric optimisation etc. This is premature optimisation that you are looking at. Even if you wanted to use sparsity, you could only do it say column-wise or row-wise, or like above note down, that you have an upper triangular form. But skipping individual 0s. Crazy. Of course copying 0s around doesn't feel right, but getting your algorithms optimised first and then worry about the above would be the way I'd go.

Also don't forget, that a lot of libraries out there cannot handle sparse matrixes, at which point you would have to put in place a recopying of the non-zero part or some bad ass expensive iterator, that would deliver the results.

Btw you would not only need the operator you noted down in your question but also the const variant; in other words:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix {
  ...
  T& operator()(size_t n, size_t m);
  const T& operator()(size_t n, size_t m) const;
  ...
};
```

There is so much more expensive stuff to optimise than `std::copy`ing stuff. For example SIMD intrinsics ... 
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/SIMDTraits.hpp